# How can I run a jQuery command when an inline link "#" is clicked or entered into the url like when linked to reddit comments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a script when an inline link is clicked, or is entered into the URL like http://site.com/index.php#comment. Similar to what happens on reddit when linked to a comment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I will give you idea..Suppose you want to deal with all a tags
html

```
<a href="http://site.com/index.php#comment">Link<a>
```

javascript

```
$('a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
var lastPart = url.split('#')[1];
if(lastPart=== 'comment') {
//do something
} else if(lastPart === 'post') {
//do something
}
});
```